# How do I get list items for unordered list using selenium(python)?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from all those list items and also from featherlight container. Code I've written to extract list items is as follows

```
driver.get('https://www.novitecgroup.com/en/brands/ferrari/roma/')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
parts_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name('tuning-parts-categories__content')
parts_list_element = parts_list.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
temp = parts_list_element[0].find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
print(temp)
```

but temp returns as a empty list. neither am I able to get data from featherlight. Thanks in advance for your help.

[1> Data within the featherlight to be extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61h08.png)

[2> webpage and respective source code I am trying to extract data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj2Jj.png)

[3> New Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es8Ii.png)

Comment: What do you want from the li tags?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I am looking to get all the visible data from this page and also from featherlight. Sorry for not being clear about what exactly I am looking for as am new to stack overflow and its my first question. I will be much precise next time around. Thank you.

Comment: Got an expected output?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Not exactly, I was also looking to get data from within featherlight with which I am stuck with. Thank you.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan nope, scraping data on featherlight for example product description, performance and max torque as in image 1 attached above. Thank you.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan After I commented that .click() line and increased wait time from 60 to 80 the code worked. But am still stuck with the image part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,60)                                 
driver.get('https://www.novitecgroup.com/en/brands/ferrari/roma/')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#cookie-confirm__submit"))).click()
parts_lists = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='tuning-parts-categories__content']/div[1]//li/a[1]")))
for x in parts_lists:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", x)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", x)
    try:
        featherlight=WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.tuning-part-popup__text")))
        product=featherlight.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//p[1]")
        if len(product) == 0:
            product = 'Empty'
        else:
            product = product[0].text
        
        box=featherlight.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//p[2]")
        if len(box) == 0:
            torque = 'Empty'
            performance = 'Empty'
        else:
            torque = box[0].text.split("\n")[1]
            performance = box[0].text.split("\n")[0]
        print(product,performance,torque)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        pass
    close=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.featherlight-close-icon.featherlight-close")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close)
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs:

```
NOVITEC N-TRONIC is a processor-controlled device to be connected to the original engine management with the Delivered Plug&Play wiring harness. The Kit includes two NOVITEC N-TRONIC modules. It is a ready to mount Plug & Play System and it is easy to install. Performance: 506 kW (688 hp) / 7.400 rpm Max. torque: 851 Nm / 3.750 rpm
NOVITEC N-TRONIC Kit, X-pipe system, catalyst-replacement pipe, SWITCHTRONIC and TECTRONIC Performance: 518 kW (704 hp) / 7.400 rpm Max. torque: 882 Nm / 3.750 rpm
NOVITEC N-TRONIC Kit, X-pipe system, sport metal catalysts, TECTRONIC and SWITCHTRONIC Performance: 514 kW (699hp) / 7.450 rpm         Max. torque: 877 Nm / 3.700 rpm
to use with NOVITEC exhaust and original exhaust system. Empty Empty
to use with NOVITEC- and original exhaust system (-4kg), 100 Zeller sport metal catalysts with reduced exhaust back pressure complete covered with high-temperature heat protection. Empty Empty
Message: 

Message: 

To use with NOVITEC sport metal catalysts or NOVITEC cat replacement pipes to avoid error indications from the exhaust system  In combination with order of a NOVITEC exhaust system Article no. F1 333 80
to use for exhaust systems with flap-regulation to open and close the flaps from the cockpit by Radio Empty Empty
```

Comment: I am looking to get data for all of those divs and also feather light container which pops up when you click one of those.

Comment: Something like this then?

Comment: I am getting following error. Please refer attached image above.

Comment: It seems to give error again on following line
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cookie-confirm__submit"))).click()

Comment: it seems to be giving me some issues as well for timeouts.